# Using std::unique_ptr with a custom deallocator for wrapping raw pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, libsvm, unique-ptr

I'm trying to use [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) for a certain complex application and, because libsvm is, mostly, a C library, one has to use a custom API function to release memory, after loading certain data. Here is what I mean:

```
struct svm_model *model;
model = svm_load_model("path to model file");

//do some processing

svm_free_and_destroy_model(&this->model);
```

And these are the definitions of the libsvm API functions that I used:

```
struct svm_model *svm_load_model(const char *model_file_name);
void svm_free_and_destroy_model(struct svm_model **model_ptr_ptr);
```

Although this works just fine, if an exception occurs while I process the model data, then I'll end up with memory leaks. To prevent this, I wrapped the above code in a class, where I call `svm_load_model` in the constructor and `svm_free_and_destroy_model` in the destructor.

Now, since we are in the era of **smart pointers**, I was thinking to get a bit more creative, and, somehow, declare the model variable as an `std::unique_ptr`, setting a pointer to `svm_free_and_destroy_model` as the custom deallocator, but, unfortunately, I'm not able to figure out if such a thing is doable. At the moment, I'm not even able to make it compile and I'm just shooting in the dark. Here is how I think it should work:

```
std::unique_ptr<struct svm_model *, /* what should I add here? */ > model (svm_load_model("path to model file"), svm_free_and_destroy_model);
```

Comment: I understand your motivation to use all that is great in C++, but there was really nothing wrong with your previous solution. Sometimes the simple answer is the best.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: What was wrong with his previous solution is that the model would _leak_ in the face of exceptions. Short of wrapping all code around with _try{...} catch(...){ if(model) free(model); throw; } if(model) free(model);_

Comment: @K-ballo, the solution I refer to is this one, which doesn't have the leak problem as it's essentially a home-brew smart pointer: "To prevent this, I wrapped the above code in a class, where I call svm_load_model in the constructor and svm_free_and_destroy_model in the destructor."

Comment: @K-ballo Not necessarily; the OP says he'd already created an RAII style wrapper for the libsvm calls, which should prevent leaks. Personally, I find that approach more useful when working with C APIs because then you can create forwarding functions for all the model processing calls as member functions within your RAII wrapper.

Comment: In this particular case, libsvm is just a small libray and I won't ever need anything else from it, so I thought I should use a smart pointer, just for the hell of it. Heck, I could even write myself a parser for the model file and use that, but, on the other hand, it's always nicer to not reinvent the wheel (even if the libsvm model parser seems a bit error-prone)...

Comment: Also, I want to learn how the advanced features of C++ are supposed to be used in practice. It's nice to read examples, but when you really try to implement them, it becomes much, much harder...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type argument to `std::unique_ptr` needs to be `T`, not `T *`. Use a lambda to call the deleter function.

```
std::unique_ptr<svm_model, void(*)(svm_model *)> 
  p( svm_load_model( "path_to_model" ), 
     []( svm_model *mdl ) { 
       svm_free_and_detroy_model( &mdl ); 
     } 
   );
```

Since VS2010 does not implement conversion of stateless lambdas to function pointers, you'll have to use `std::function` to get this to work.

```
std::unique_ptr<svm_model, std::function<void(svm_model*)>>
  p( svm_load_model("path_to_model"), 
     []( svm_model *mdl ) {
       svm_free_and_destroy_model( &mdl );
     }
   );
```

Comment: That is a very interesting approach, but I get an error regarding the first parameter for the constructor: `error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr(svm_model *,void (__cdecl *const &)(svm_model *&))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'svm_model *' to 'svm_model *'`

Comment: @MihaiTodor I got similar errors when I was using `struct svm_model` in all the function calls, but was able to get rid of them by dropping the `struct` ... not sure why. Also, the solution I posted will not work in VS2010 because it doesn't implement conversion of stateless lambdas to function pointers. I'll add another solution that should work as well.

Comment: I think you made an error here `[]( svm_load_model *mdl )`, which should be `[]( svm_model *mdl )`, but it works and it also makes sense. I have one more question, though: what happens if svm_load_model returns NULL? How can I test that?

Comment: @MihaiTodor Oops, copy-paste error, fixed it. You can check for `nullptr` by using `if(!p) { throw something; }` after constructing the `unique_ptr`

Comment: OK, after this, maybe I'll start to figure out how to use this beast. Let's say that I want to declare `p` as a class member. How would I call the constructor with the `svm_load_model("path_to_model"), []( svm_model *mdl ) {svm_free_and_destroy_model( &mdl );}` parameters after the class constructor initializes `p`? Can it even initialize `p` with a default value? Is it possible to supply the custom deallocator when declaring `p`?

Comment: @MihaiTodor The type of member variable `p` would be `std::unique_ptr<svm_model, void(*)(svm_model *)>` (or the `std::function` variant). Then you can initialize it in the constructor's initialization list using the call to `svm_load_model` and supplying the deleter lambda. By default, `unique_ptr` initializes the internal pointer to `nullptr` but I'm not sure about the custom deleter case, VS2010 compiles successfully though. To initialize it later, you'll have to create a temporary `unique_ptr` of the same type and `std::move` it into `p`

Comment: That's nice. Really, really nice. Thank you very much. I am reading through these new C++ move semantics and smart pointers and your explanations really helped me understand them better.

Answer (score 0):

The *deleter* for `unique_ptr` should be a function taking just a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer. You could try:

```
void svm_deleter(svm_model*& model)
{
    svm_free_and_detroy_model(&model);
}

....

std::unique_ptr< svm_model, void(*)(svm_model*&) >(
    svm_load_model("path to model file")
  , &svm_deleter
);
```

Comment: I get an error regarding the first parameter for the constructor: `error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx>::unique_ptr(svm_model *,void (__cdecl *const &)(svm_model *&))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'svm_model *' to 'svm_model *'`

Comment: @Mihai Todor: That's an odd error... try dropping the reference from both the deleter function and the unique_ptr declaration.

Comment: I think it may be caused by some Visual Studio 2010 compiler issue... And it's not caused by the deleter construct, apparently.